# How to write c language modulo 2 with use mpfr function?

Tags: c, modulo, mpfr

Here is the example of code in c language:

```
int i;

for (i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
if (i % 2 == 0) 
{
// do something
}
}
```

But i variable is standard integer. I need this code of modulo 2 with use mpfr_t type and proper function. [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) library.

I could use while loop and increment i variable in the loop:

```
mpfr_t i;
mpfr_init2(i, 100);

mpfr_set_si (i, 0, MPFR_RNDD);

while(mpfr_cmpabs(i,100)<0)

{
mpfr_add_si(i, i, 1, MPFR_RNDD);

// how to write modulo 2 ?

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just add 2 to `i` in each iteration instead of 1.

Comment: I can't. I need i variable as even and odd numbers.

Comment: That is not what your question shows. It shows only code that needs to do something when `i` is even, and that is easily accomplished by initializing `i` to zero and adding increments of two. If you need something else, update the post to show all the constraints of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do something with values of `i` that are zero modulo two, this is easily accomplished by initializing `i` to zero (or other desired start value) and adding two to it in each iteration.

If you need to iterate `i` through all integers but selectively do just some code when `i` is even or odd, then a way to do this is to keep both the `mpfr` counter and a separate ordinary variable:

```
mpfr_t i;
mpfr_init2(i, 100);

//  Define r to hold the residue of i modulo 2.
int r;

for (
    // Start loop with i = 0 and r = 0.
    mpfr_set_si(i, 0, MPFR_RNDD), r = 0;

    // Iterate until i reaches endpoint.
    mpfr_cmpabs(i, 100) < 0;

    // Increment both i and residue r.
    mpfr_add_si(i, i, 1, MPFR_RNDD), r = (r+1) % 2)
{
    // Put code for each iteration here.

    // Test whether the residue modulo 2 is 0, equivalent to i is even.
    {
        // Put code for when i is even here.
    }
}
```

Another solution is to unroll the loop so two iterations are written out, while putting the code for each iteration into a function:

```
mpfr_t i;
mpfr_init2(i, 100);

mpfr_set_si(i, 0, MPFR_RNDD);

while (mpfr_cmpabs(i, 100) < 0)
{
    //  Do things for a first value of i per loop.
    DoStuff(i);

    // Put code for when i is even here.

    //  Increment i to odd value.
    mpfr_add_si(i, i, 1, MPFR_RNDD);

    //  Do things for a second value of i per loop..
    DoStuff(i);

    //  Increment i to even value.
    mpfr_add_si(i, i, 1, MPFR_RNDD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a general question (i.e. you are not necessarily in a loop like in your example) and you know that the variable `i` is an integer, then a solution could be to do `mpfr_fmod_ui(r,i,2,MPFR_RNDN)` with the output precision 1 for `r` (the rounding mode doesn't matter since the exact result is either 0 or 1, thus exactly representable in any precision).

An alternate solution (probably faster) would be to divide `i` by 2 with `mpfr_div_2ui(i,i,1,MPFR_RNDN)` and use `mpfr_integer_p` on the result: true means that the modulo is 0, and false means that the modulo is 1. You can restore `i` with `mpfr_mul_2ui(i,i,1,MPFR_RNDN)`. Note that these functions are very fast when reusing the input as the result, since in this case, just the exponent is modified.

Comment: Thanks @vinc17 I have solved this in similar way with use: mpfr_fmod(r, i, two, MPFR_RNDD); if(mpfr_cmpabs_ui(r,0)==0) { // do something} but this way my procedure to compute Pi with Long Leibniz formula is slower than previous version with use mpfr_pow (power, one, x, MPFR_RNDD); Please check my CPILL and CPILL2 procedures here: https://github.com/SylwesterBogusiak/ComputePi. I want to compute Pi with this procedures up to the limit of 10^18 or 10^21 or bigger limit. But now for 10^12 my PC was calculating 550044.623 seconds, it's 6 days. I need to maximize the speed of the main loop.

Comment: @SylwesterBogusiak In your particular case, you should unroll the loop to do 2 iterations as suggested in the other answer, which is better than just doing `if (is_even(i)) { /* even case */ } else { /* odd case */ }` in your loop.